# Internet Explorer not selecting Elements on Webpage

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

I am running Selenium to test a specific area of my companies webpage. What I am trying to do seems relatively easy in theory, but I have ran into several obstacles. Can someone please tell me why the URL is opening but won't select the "Services" Hyperlink?

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","Path to IE/IEDriverServer_64.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
driver.get("https://www.ups.com/us/en/Home.page");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*/div[@id='ups-header']/nav[@id='ups-navItems']/ul[@class='ups-navItems_primary']/li[@class='ups-navMenu ups-menu'][3]/a[@id='ups-menuLinks2']")).click();
```

As I stated earlier, in theory this should open up UPS's homepage and select the "Services" tab on the top right of the page. Instead it just goes to UPS.com homepage and stays there.

I have driver.findElement(By.xpath........); in this example but I have tried findElement(By.name & partialLinkText

Can anyone give me a solution besides update to latest version(s)?

**Metadata:**
Windows 10,
JAVA 10,
Internet Explorer (Unfortunately) 11.4.

Thanks in advance!

Edit with additonal HTML structure:

This is a portion of the  HTML I am working with. This HTML belongs to the Services link I want to click in my automation:

```
<a role="button" href="#" class="ups-analytics ups-menu_toggle" data- 
content-block-id="M1" data-event-id="22" aria-expanded="false" id="ups- 
menuLinks2" aria-controls="ups-menuPanel2">Services<span class="ups-mobnav- 
arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span></a><div class="ups-menu_list ups-cols-3" 
aria-hidden="true" role="region" id="ups-menuPanel2" aria-labelledby="ups- 
menuLinks2">
<h2 class="ups-med_show">Services</h2>
<div class="ups-menu_listCols">
```

Comment: By the way, I am not getting an error in the console.

Comment: Is this working fine with chrome and firefox?

Comment: Firefox tries, but wont open due to our proxy. Chrome opens, but wont go to the URL.

Comment: Could you please provide image of your html structure.

Comment: I have updated the html structure for that specific link I want clicked

Comment: Try with this xpath :- //a[contains(@id,'ups-menuLinks2')]

Answer (score 1):

*Internet Explorer v11* doesn't opens the *url* on my system but with *Selenium v3.12.0*, *ChromeDriver 2.39* and *Chrome v67.0* the following solution clicks on the element with text as **Services** just perfecto:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.ups.com/us/en/Home.page");
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Services")).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Services_clicked]

Comment: Sometimes the element is not clickable immadiately and some kind of waiting is needed. I successfuly use wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));

Answer (score 0):

This was tricky for IE , for some reasons all the xpath i tried seems to not work. This might be due to some capabitlites that needs to be added. I haven't looked into it in details but its working for me in Firefox:

```
        String baseURL = "https://www.ups.com/us/en/Home.page";
    WebDriver driver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//path to//geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(baseURL);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement service=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/header/div/nav/ul[1]/li[3]"));
    System.out.println(service.getText());
    service.click();
```

If you have issues with your Firefox. Please share the stacktrace so we can help. This code perfectly works for Firefox